# How to get retrieve data via ajax in my case?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an weird issue in my php and javascript.

I have something in php like

```
$testData = array(
       'prop1' => true,
       'prop2' => 2,
       'name' => 'testname',
       'number' => 123
);

echo json_encode($testData);
```

in Javascript

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    url: phpfile,
    global: false,
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
        console.log(result.prop1)
        console.log(result.prop2)
    }
```

I was able to get result from `console.log(result)` but I can't get anything from `console.log(result.prop1)` nor `console.log(result.prop2)`. Did I do something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax request?

Comment: what was your output from console.log(result) what does console.log(typeof(result)) give you

Comment: {"prop1":true,"prop2":2,"name":"testname","number":123}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to get json objects from ajax.

**First:** (Recomended)
You have to define dataType property with `JSON`,

example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    url: phpfile,
    global: false,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
        console.log(result.prop1)
        console.log(result.prop2)
    }
});
```

in this case, jQuery will process the result as `JSON` and then you can access it's object property, if it is not an `JSON`, then it will go for error event.

**Second:**
The other way to parse the object is by using `JSON.parse()` function because the data you are getting is just string.

example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    url: phpfile,
    global: false,
    success: function(result){
        var data = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.prop1);
        console.log(data.prop2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Another way exists (for answer completeness, but I wouldn't recommended doing it): If you don't specify the datatype, it'll try and guess what type of data it is from the type of response received. By default it'll be plain html, so it receives it as will assume it's just a string (which is what is happening in this question). Before you output your data intended as the response, you could set a header `header('Content-Type: application/json');` which'll mean the response is interpreted as json.

Answer (score 2):

You have transform the json from php

```
success: function(result) {
  var res = JSON.parse(result)
  console.log(result)
  console.log(res.prop1)
  console.log(res.prop2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you encode your array in PHP to send it to Javascript, by writing  `json_encode($testData);` so to get it on javascript side you have to use `JSON.parse(yourencodedArray)` by using this you are able to get values inside your array.

```
var data = JSON.parse(yourencodedArray);
var dat1 = data.prop1;
var dat2 = data.prop2;
```

**JSON.parse** is able to decode your encoded Array.